# Do limit groups satisfy Howson's theorem?

Tags: gr.group-theory, lo.logic, geometric-group-theory

> Let $G$ be a limit group, and let $A,B \leq G$ be finitely generated
>   subgroups generating $G$ (i.e. $\langle A \cup B \rangle = G$). Must
>   $A \cap B$ be finitely generated?

Recall that a limit group is a group whose existential theory (the set of true sentences in first order theory which use only the quantifier $\exists$ and not $\forall$) is the same as that of a nonabelian free group.

Howson's theorem says that the answer is positive in case that $G$ is free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is 'yes'. A geometric proof, showing in fact that every finitely generated subgroup of a limit group is relatively quasiconvex, was given by [Dahmani](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0203258).

Comment: I think we have the same answer

Comment: Looks like we do!

Answer (score 7):

They do, see theoerrm 4.7. http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0203258.pdf by Dahmani.